# Площадь треугольника. Множество точек на плоскости

Tags: python

На плоскости задано множество точек с целочисленными координатами. Необходимо найти максимально возможную площадь невырожденного (т.е. имеющего ненулевую площадь) треугольника, одна вершина которого расположена в начале координат, а две другие лежат на биссектрисах углов, образованных осями координат, и при этом принадлежат заданному множеству. Если такого треугольника не существует, необходимо вывести соответствующее сообщение. Напишите эффективную по времени и по используемой памяти программу для решения этой задачи.
 Пример входных данных:

```
3
6 6
-8 8
9 7
```

Пример выходных данных для приведённого выше примера входных данных:
48

Моя программа:

```
a = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(0, 2*n):
    a.append(int(input()))
for k in range(0, 2*n): 
    z = ((a[k]-a[k+2])**2 + (a[k+1]-a[k+3])**2)**0,5
    b = ((a[k]-a[k+4])**2 + (a[k+1]-a[k+5])**2)**0,5
    c = ((a[k+2]-a[k+4])**2 + (a[k+3]-a[k+5])**2)**0,5
    p = (z+b+c)*0,5
    S = (p*(p+z)*(p+b)*(p+c))**0,5
if S > 0: 
    print(S)
else: 
    print('Не существует')
```

Не понимаю, что не так, помогите :(

Comment: А что "не так"?

Comment: В чем конкретно ваша проблема, объясните пожалуйста?

Comment: Нужно подумать, что означает `две другие лежат на биссектрисах углов, образованных осями координат, `. И да, имея координаты, площадь следует считать не по Герону, а через векторное произведение.